# Unity Facebook Canvas inject background image

Tags: c#, javascript, html, facebook, unity-game-engine

I have my game made with unity and with facebook integrated.All works nice, but i cant change background image, i dont know anything about html :). I can do manualy with developer tools in chrome, but i cant do injecting code.
i have this code.

```
private void ConfigureCanvas(){
        Debug.Log("CONFIGURE FACEBOOK CANVAS ");
        // INJECT TOP ADS

        string injectionAdsFacebook =
            "var headerElement = document.createElement('div'); " +
                "headerElement.id = ('adsWebFacebook')  ; " +
                "headerElement.textContent = ('Check out our other great games: ...');" +
                "headerElement.style.width = 400; " +
                "headerElement.style.height = 200; " +
                "headerElement.style.marginLeft = (window.innerWidth - 400)/2;" +
                "headerElement.style.marginRight = (window.innerWidth - 400)/2;" +
                "var body = document.getElementById('unityPlayerEmbed');" +
                "var insertionPoint = body.children[0]; " +
                "body.insertBefore(headerElement, insertionPoint);";

        Application.ExternalEval(injectionAdsFacebook);

        // Execute javascript in iframe to keep the player centered and recalculate resolution
        string javaScript = @"
                    window.onresize = function() {
                    var width = window.innerWidth;
                    var height = window.innerHeight;

                    var marginX = width * 0.1;
                    var marginY = height *0.1;

                    var appHeight = (( window.innerHeight - marginY) / 500) * 500;
                    var appWidth = (appHeight *16) /10; 

                    if(appWidth > window.innerWidth){
                        appWidth = (( window.innerWidth - marginX) / 800) * 800;
                        appHeight = (appWidth *10) /16; 

                    }

                    var unity = UnityObject2.instances[0].getUnity();
                    var unityDiv = document.getElementById(""unityPlayerEmbed"");

                    unity.style.width = appWidth + ""px"";
                    unity.style.height = appHeight + ""px"";

                    unityDiv.style.marginLeft = (width - appWidth)/2 + ""px"";
                    unityDiv.style.marginTop = (height - appHeight)/2 + ""px"";
                    unityDiv.style.marginRight = (width - appWidth)/2 + ""px"" ;
                    unityDiv.style.marginBottom = (height - appHeight)/2 + ""px"";
                }

                window.onresize(); // force it to resize now";
        Application.ExternalCall(javaScript);



        string changeCanvasBackground = 

                "var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body');" +
                "body[0].background-image =  \"url('https://tictacpuzzlesfb.parseapp.com/backgroundsFaceCanvas/spaceCanvasBack.png')\";" +
                "body[0].background-size = 'cover'";

        Application.ExternalEval(changeCanvasBackground);
    }
```

Well if any can give me a solution, i think this would be pretty easy for a html programmer,if i can i want do with ExternalEval(changaCanvasBackground),every time i get a error like its a bad assigment i try many options and ever get the same error

P.d: sorry for my english, its pretty low :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is here for about 3 monthos now, but I stumbled across a similar problem and this post helped me to get some ideas on how to solve it. Here is my solution to change the Facebook canvas page of a unity game:

**Facebook app config page:**

-Unity Integration: YES

-Fixed Width: NO

-Fixed Height: NO

**Unity Editor configs:**

-Set the webplayer resolution desired (mine was 760 x 800)

-On any script call this from Start():

```
private void changeCanvasBackground()
    {
        string script = "document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.backgroundImage=\"url('https://YOURSECUREURL.COM/background.jpg')\";";

        Application.ExternalEval(script);

        //This FB.Canvas.SetResolution should set to the W and H that is set on your build preferences in unity editor.
        FB.Canvas.SetResolution(760, 800, false, 0, FBScreen.CenterHorizontal(), FBScreen.CenterVertical());
    }
```

Thanks.